# how I can change the title of the page at Angular2 by not making change at app.component.ts ?

Tags: angular, jakarta-ee, typescript

As I read from Angular2 Forums, we can change the title of the html page by making changes on app.component.ts and app.module.ts. Is there any way to make this change on a single page without making any change on app.component.ts? Because I have too many components and I do not want to show title name change on all the pages or components ? I can make changes on single component's ts ? Could you please provide me sample for that ?

Regards
Alper

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hello Nizet. I want to change title of the html page. I do not want to show it like "Angular Quick Start". I have too many components and I only want to change title on one component. Can I do it by making changes only component's typeScript page or I have to make changes on app.components.ts ?

Comment: Again, unclear. When should the title change? Once changed, should it stay as is forever?

Comment: yep. Thanks I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AppModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    Title
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AppComponent**

```
export class AppComponent {
  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }
  public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
  }
}
```

Comment: i called it from constructor as you mentioned and added titleService in the constructor . It is working fine.Thank you